# webdriver.chrome executable path is returning an unexpected error message?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

First time using selenium and webdriver and when I try to point to where I have my chromedriver saved off I get an error message. See code sample and error below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:/Users/PPKXB/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException                        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In [31], line 2
      1 #"S:\ppkxb\chromedriver_win32"
----> 2 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r"C:/Users/PPKXB/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")

File c:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py:80, in WebDriver.__init__(self, executable_path, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, chrome_options, service, keep_alive)
     77 if not service:
     78     service = Service(executable_path, port, service_args, service_log_path)
---> 80 super().__init__(
     81     DesiredCapabilities.CHROME["browserName"],
     82     "goog",
     83     port,
     84     options,
     85     service_args,
     86     desired_capabilities,
     87     service_log_path,
     88     service,
     89     keep_alive,
     90 )

File c:\Program Files\Python38\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py:104, in ChromiumDriver.__init__(self, browser_name, vendor_prefix, port, options, service_args, desired_capabilities, service_log_path, service, keep_alive)
    101 self.service.start()
    103 try:
--> 104     super().__init__(
...
</blockquote>
</FONT>
</BODY></HTML>
```

Would anyone have any idea where I'm going wrong? Any guidance greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `raw` path you need to use the single backslash for the path as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\PPKXB\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
```

As an alternative you can also use the escaped backslash for the path as:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = 'C:\\Users\\PPKXB\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe')
```

Comment: both Suggestions didn't work unfortunately, still receiving the same error.